# Error: std::bad_alloc Rstudio

Tags: c++, r

After running this code:

```
t1 <-Sys.time()
df.m <- left_join(df.h,daRta3,by=c("year","month","MA","day"))
t2 <- Sys.time()
difftime(t2,t1)
```

I have this error.

> **Error: std::bad_alloc**

The dimension of the matrix that I have tried to create is `74495*2695 = 180.10^6` rows.

The computer in which I run the code has 20 GB of RAM

I tried the `memory.limit()` but it did not solve my issue.

Comment: The physical amount of RAM is not only thing that's relevant. Are compiling as a 64-bit application?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please read the info about [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and how to give a [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example/5963610). This will make it much easier for others to help you.

Comment: 74495*2695=200,764,025. Besides the calculation also a suggestion: a possible solution is to 'cut' your data sets in multiple blocks and apply the left_join on the different sets.

Comment: @ Algirdas Preidžius yeah i am compiling as 64-bit Application. @MarcelG that's finally how i manage to solve the problem, I divided my database into multiple datasets et done the left join. It is still slow but it work. Thank you guys for your help

Answer (score 0):

1. Examine cardinality of your join key

   - Is the `c("year","month","MA","day")` unique in both `df.h` and `daRta3`?
   - What are the most frequent values?
2. `NA` values. `left_join` can treat `NA` values as equal or different:

   ```
   > tibble(x = c(NA, NA, NA)) %>% left_join(., ., by = 'x')
   # A tibble: 9 x 1
     x    
     <lgl>
   1 NA   
   2 NA   
   3 NA   
   4 NA   
   5 NA   
   6 NA   
   7 NA   
   8 NA   
   9 NA   
   > tibble(x = c(NA, NA, NA)) %>% left_join(., ., by = 'x', na_matches = 'never')
   # A tibble: 3 x 1
     x    
     <lgl>
   1 NA   
   2 NA   
   3 NA
   ```
3. If order and values in `c("year","month","MA","day")` can be guaranteed to be the same then simple `cbind` or `bind_cols` might be an efficient solution